# selecting other columns with this query

Tags: mysql

I have this query which calculates the the count of total books which has same name . I wanted to select other fields like for each item I want its other columns too

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name)
  FROM b6j_items 
 GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
ORDER BY name desc
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the columns?  Do you get any errors?

Comment: yes I tried adding more colums in name , columns it throws this
 Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'new_booksmandala.b6j_items.sku' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Imagine that you have 2 books with the same name, but different, for example, year... what value of 2 possible must be returned? and why?

Comment: can you add mysql sample output in your question,I think you need to use sum function